# Can I make the Jquery slideViewer autoplay?

Tags: jquery

Any thoughts on making the slideViewr plugin from (2007-2009 Gian Carlo Mingati | design and development for interactive media) autoplay?

I tried upgrading to the slideViewerPro, but did not like the thumbnails and other stuff.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you basically have 3 options here:

**(1)** - Use slideViewPro, but disable thumbnails using the `thumbsVis:false` option as shown below

```
$("div#noui").slideViewerPro({ 
    galBorderWidth: 0, 
    autoslide: true,  
    thumbsVis: false, 
    shuffle: true 
 });
```

**(2)** - Switch to using the **[jQuery cycle plug-in](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)** instead

**(3)** - Edit the source code of original `slideViewer` and add your own `autoslide` implementation by using timers and firing the click event on the navigation.

If I were in your shoes, I would stick with option 1.

Answer (score 2):

The above doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Instead I recommend tweaking it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theLinks;
var nCount = 0;
var theTimerID;

function init(){
    $("div#mygalone").slideView();
    theLinks = jQuery('#stripTransmitter0 a');

        //for kill interval purposes
        theTimerID = setInterval("autoSlide()", 5000);
}
function autoSlide(){
    jQuery.each(theLinks, function(i){
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('current')){
            jQuery(theLinks[((i+1 < theLinks.length) ? (i+1) : 0)] ).trigger("click");
            return false;
        }
    });
}

$(window).bind("load", init );
</script>
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me without having to change to another library

Answer (score 0):

```
Here´s my implementation:

var theLinks;
var nCount = 0;
var theTimerID;

function init(){
    $("div#mygalone").slideView();
    theLinks = jQuery('#stripTransmitter0 a');

        //for kill interval purposes
        theTimerID = setInterval("autoSlide()", 8000);
}
function autoSlide(){
    nCount++;
    if(nCount == theLinks.length ) nCount = 0;
    console.log(theLinks);
    jQuery(theLinks[nCount]).trigger("click");
}

$(window).bind("load", init );
```